# Disabled checkboxes if more than three checked in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I've created a table in angular material and i will compare the data of three rows. 
Now i have to disable all other checkboxes if i have three boxes on checked. 
I know i could use the [disabled] state from the material table, but if i checked three boxes, all boxes are disabled than. But i have to deselect the checked boxes so i could change the collection.

How could i write a if else statement?

[Working tree](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jlk4vf-by64b7)

Comment: Are you aware, that you can select more checkboxes by clicking the row right now?

Comment: Yes but not if you have more than this max three checked values. 
Solution from Z.Bolbol was fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add !selection.isSelected(row) in the disabled state :

```
 <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selectRow($event, row) : null" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row) == true" [disabled]="disableBoxes && !selection.isSelected(row)"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jlk4vf-gqy4jz)

Comment: thank you i figured it at the same time :) 
I didn't know that i can use it.

But if i deselect the checkboxes they are disabled.

Comment: Thx a lot, the solution is to simple :D